# Facebooks detects a virus in our android app

Tags: android, facebook, upload, virus, review

We're developing an app which uses Facebook login with `publish_actions` permission. This permission requires the app to be uploaded to and reviewed by Facebook. I set up everything correctly and the app works fine. I tested our Facebook features with a test app.

Now when I try to upload our app to Facebook for the review I get an error saying: "Virus Detected in File".

Google has no results for that. What can I do? I din't implement a virus intentionally.

[image: Virus Detected in File]

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I did: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1541137142809164
It seems they can't help me, despite it is a Facebook bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Obfuscate your code using Proguard.

**Long story:**

I threw our APK into [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com). One of 57 engines - **ClamAV** - found a threat named **Andr.Trojan.Locker**. I downloaded a compiled version of ClamAV to test locally. After unzipping the APK ClamAV didn't find anything. However if I zip compress the classes.dex again, ClamAV finds the threat again. So we can safely suppose the is no real threat.
As we had to obfuscate our code anyway, I activated Proguard and checked it with ClamAV --> the threat was gone - no virus detected. There was a chance that Facebook still detects a virus, but it seems Facebook is also using this open source virus scan engine for virus detection purposes. Furthermore it seems *Proguard also obfuscates malicious code... ;-)*